# Is there oil without olives?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, cibus

Is the Latin word *oleum* ("oil") related to *oliva* ("olive")?
If yes, how?

The two words look similar, but *oleum* does not look like a regular derivative to me.
Many dictionaries mention that *oleum* means "oil" or "olive oil", but that could be just because olive oil was the most common oil in antiquity.
Another option that comes to mind is that *oleum* comes from *olere* due to its smell.

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=oleum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) does not discuss etymology within Latin, but links to a Greek word.
In Greek the similarity is more obvious (*ἔλαιον=oleum* and *ἔλαιος=oliva*), but it is not clear if *oleum* and *oliva* were borrowed from Greek separately, if *oleum* was derived from *oliva* in Latin, or if something else happened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current **communis opinio** is both Latin words oleum and oliva were borrowed from Greek, which, in its turn, are of Pre-Greek origin (e.g. [Beekes 2009/2016](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=greek&id=gr2172), Ernout & Meillet 2001); cf. [Miller 2014](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9781614512950/9781614512950.25/9781614512950.25.xml) "there are cultural and phonological reasons for thinking Latin borrowed it from Greek" (p. 31).

[Miller 2014](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9781614512950/9781614512950.25/9781614512950.25.xml) writes that

> "Since Attic-Ionic lost /w/ prehistorically, Greek words borrowed into Latin with v /w/ are either from a West Greek (Doric) dialect, or possibly early enough to have been Mycenaean loans" (p.31).

Latin oleum < *olēwom < *eleiwom < Gk. *élaiwon (Miller 2014), cf. ἔλαιον

Latin oliva < Gk. *elaíwā ([Beekes 2009/2016](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=greek&id=gr2172)), cf. ἐλαία

All of the sound changes above are well-known and described in any historical Latin grammar worth reading, e.g. Weiss 2009/2011 (the first book I grabbed from my bookshelves).

- *e > o/_ɫ (p. 139);
- ai > ei > e (> i) (a-weakening, Weiss tells us, precedes monophthongization, p. 120);
- *ei > *ẹ̄ > e (p. 143) etc.

As for a possible Etruscan intermediary hypothesis suggested by TKR (was it borrowed directly from Greek or via Etruscan?), this is highly speculative. As Clackson and Horrocks 2007/2011 write,

> "All languages of central Italy participate in borrowing words for material artefacts from Greek. **Often we may be unable to tell whether a word came directly from Greek or via the medium of another language**: Greek *kulίkʰna 'cup' borrowed as Latin *culigna*, Etruscan *culicna*, Oscan *culchina*/*culcfna*" (p. 46; emphasis mine — Alex B.).

For more information we will need to look it up in De Simone 1968–1970 and Watmough 1997 — and I will. I encourage you to read these books too!

Comment: Does Miller mean "from Greek as opposed to Etruscan" or some other specific language that has been proposed? (Btw, the order of "Gk. olaiwom < Gk. olēwom" should be the other way around -- and neither form is Greek; the *el > ol* change is Latin. The same intermediate steps could be added for *olīva*; its Greek source is *elaíwā*, note accent and vowel length.)

Comment: Any particular reason for "cf. ἐλαιόω" rather than ἔλαιον, which is surely the source? Btw, the change *ai > ei* isn't clear to me (and I can't find a relevant discussion in Weiss) -- wouldn't it normally show up as *ae*?

Comment: @TKR it's funny - i just noticed it five min ago on my iPad and just turned on my laptop to fix it, thinking how you're going to mention this. :) Fixing it right now. In the future, feel free to fix obvious typos!

Comment: Will do! I assumed it was a typo but didn't change it because I can't access the Brill dictionary from home (which may be a reason to link to open-access sites like Perseus, btw).

Comment: @TKR ok, will link to open-access dictionaries next time. Re: ai > ei see the updated answer.

Comment: Oh, of course -- it's just regular weakening. Should have thought of that. Thanks!